# What options are there for door stops away from a wall?

Tags: doors, safety

I have a number of doors in different situations where opening the door fully will hit various things, in all cases I don't have a wall behind the door to fix a normal stop to.

The only solution I can currently think of are the stops you screw in the floor, but they would be a trip hazard.  I assume using those floor stops near the hinge would be a bad idea because it would wrench the hinges?

What other options are there for preventing a door opening too far?

For what it's worth these are the different situations:

- Door corner collides with sloping ceiling when open 135deg
- Door face collides with kitchen cupboard knob at 90 deg
- Door edge collides with bookcase at 150 deg

Answer (score 2):

I've used floor stops -- either permanently mounted to the floor or wall if that can be done without creating a trip hazard, or the old step-to-apply, step-to-release spring stops with rubber feet many of us remember from classrooms.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a door closer that can hold open [like this](http://m.lowes.com/pd/TELL-MANUFACTURING-INC-Commercial-Grade-1-Door-Closer-Adjustable/3018404?cm_mmc=SCE_PLA_ONLY-_-ToolsAndHardware-_-SosDoorWindowHardware-_-3018404:TELL_MANUFACTURING,_INC.&CAWELAID=&kpid=3018404&CAGPSPN=pla&k_clickID=ea985018-4ea8-457c-a30f-c94373a534b8). A bit expensive but it may solve your problem without creating a trip hazard. Other than this a rubber wedge type stop would be useful, but it sounds like you want something better than a wedge.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at hinge stops, and use them in pairs (or even triples). They apply a large force to the hinge screws and the door skin, so using multiples distributes the load.

[image]
*For reference only.*

If your doors are very heavy, consider a closer as recommended by Ed Beal.

Comment: If you use these, I would strongly recommend that you also replace the hinge screws with ones that are long enough to bite into the jack stud behind the door frame so that the force of the door being stopped isn't applied to the frame itself, just make sure you don't ever-tighten the screws and deform the door frame.

Comment: Not a bad idea, though I've never actually seen a hinge stop pull screws out. They usually dent the door or bend the hinge leaves first.

Comment: Door frames in my house are MDF. 'nough said?

Comment: Uggh. Yes indeed. I installed a lot of MDF trim back when, and I'll never use it on my personal projects. Even particle board is better.

Comment: My frames are solid wood.  No dents or other marks from the hinge pin stop, but it has pulled the screws sideways and widened the holes they were in enough that they no longer bite into the wood.  It may not have helped that I haven't been vigilant about keeping the pin down — these stops tend to work the pin up out of the hinge.  And even longer screws aren't gonna close up those holes that have been created near the surface of the wood.

Comment: Hinge stops are generally considered to be a poor choice -- they can not only damage the frame, but the door hardware as well due to the high forces involved. See the comments on [this blog post](https://idighardware.com/2017/12/wwyd-hinge-pin-stops/) for some commentary from architect & specifier types on them...

Answer (score 0):

You can get magnetic [concealed door stops](https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/1478765816/invisible-door-stopper-door-suction) that are almost flush with the door.

Comment: Without any indication of your interest in the etsy shop you're linking to, I can only assume this is spam.